# Databinding & performances : is the cost of a databinding high?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, binding

I am designing a very simple C# WPF application, following the MVVM pattern, with a `ListView` showing around 10 items (bound to an object containing an application's details) with a `Checkbox`, allowing the user to select some applications, and then click on the button "Launch".

This application is aiming at specific users of the company (an investment bank) who always have a lot of extremely heavy applications launched (real-time financial softwares, i.e. *Bloomberg* for example).

While my application is perfectly smooth on my PC & the IT team members' PCs, I started deploying the app to end-users and experienced a kinda bad situation: **one click**, really, **just one**, on an item, takes around 2 seconds to activate a `CheckBox`.

They are already using a basic Winforms application which is perfectly smooth for this kind of actions.

I am therefore asking myself a question, which would seem quite stupid according to the fact that `DataBinding` is the core of MVVM, but **is DataBinding implying a higher cost than EventListeners?**

Thanks!

Comment: How well does WPF (w/o databinding) perform on those PC's? It could be a graphics or (lack of) memory issue.

Comment: No.  What, you were expecting something different?  They are having some other issue.  Vidya drivers, other applications, etc etc.

Comment: I have forms with dozens of databinding scenarios and it flies. Where I've run in to some issues with Silverlight/WPF is in animations, but often that's a result of either bad VSM code or an over-animation happy designer.

Comment: WPF can be slow at times by usually it is because of hardware requirements. Even the new WPF point interpolation can be a stress on lowend previous gen intel integrated graphics. Are those PCs any good for today use? If not better to stick to winforms. Have you tried some advanced WPF animation? If that works ok, then probably the problem is somewhere in your code.

Comment: I have an animation (classic loading circle) which is running with an acceptable speed (though not perfectly smooth). I'd genuinely conclude that the only problem is requirements, even though customers do have correct configurations for running WPF, the only problem is that they run plenty of CPU-intensive applications. I'll try running another WPF applications on their machines and then see what happens. Still, I'm relieved to see that as I thought Databinding is not heavier (otherwise what's be the point on using it? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on a VoIP application that had to mantain a huge contact list and each contact had several information shown on his contact card (basically a ListBoxItem),that were changing with an high frequency.  We did experience some issues but not as bad as you say.
Two things come to my mind:
- how many bindings do you have and how many NotifyPropertyChanged are generated? It might happen that for one property that changes in your model you generate too many events (just a possibility)
- you speak about clicking a CheckBox. What happens in your setter? How heavy is it? Can you use an async operation? Sometimes it can get tricky to use controls like checkboxes and push buttons if the action they trigger can take a long time.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: The only thing I have is a list with booleans in it, clicking on a checkbox updates the associated boolean, I'll check on how it impacts the rest of the program, but my debugger ensures me that the setter is called once, and seems like nothing else is called after that :/

Comment: Can you post some code fragments? It would help in understanding the case better. It sounds strange that if you click a checkbox, it takes so long to update, unless the pc is horribly slow.